# Bordes redondeados en tablas + Sombra Swift 3

Tags: swift

Como puedo hacer que los bordes de mi tabla se vean redondos y no rectos.
al igual que en cada linea.

Y agregar una sombra a la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los bordes de la tabla sean redondos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Te refieres a un `UITableView`? Añade una imagen o algo para que entendamos que necesitas

Answer (score 2):

mete tu tabla en una `UIView` contenedor (la tabla con constraints 0 a los 4 bordes de esta view)

```
@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
```

después puedes hacer, por ejemplo en `ViewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // bordes redondeados
    self.tableview.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    self.tableview.layer.masksToBounds = true

    // sombras
    self.containerView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.containerView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.containerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 5)
    self.containerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    self.containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer los bordes redondeados puedes realizar:

```
self.tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 5 //Este valor es el radio que van a tener los bordes
```